# How to get DB Path and Name

Tags: android, database, sqlite, path

Can I get a DB Path and Name with this?

```
Paths.getDbPath();

Paths.getDbName();
```

I think if we are using a database in our application, can we store that in the assets folder and rename it?

Comment: "Paths" is not a class in the Android framework, so there's no way to answer your question without you telling us where you got it from.

Comment: private static String DB_PATH = Paths.getDbPath();
private static String DB_NAME = Paths.getDbName();    I saw this line of code in one of the project

Comment: You are *still* not telling us from where you are getting the class.

Comment: Here is _my_ code                                                 private void getInfoFromDB(int id)
 {
  SQLiteDatabase sql=null;
  Cursor cur=null;
  Cursor cur1=null;
  int no_of_rows=0;
  try
  {
   sql = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(Paths.geDBPath() + Paths.getDbName(), null, 
     SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
  
  }catch (SQLiteException e) 
  {
   // TODO: handle exception
   
  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with Paths, so I cannot answer your question.
But I can tell you how to copy your DB to Assets

Method in DBHelper

```
public void exportDatabase(String destin) throws IOException {

    File sourceFile = new File(getReadableDatabase().getPath());    
    File destinationDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "DBNAME");
    FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(sourceFile, destinationDir);


    String sourcetemp = "source.db";
    String destintemp = destin + ".db";
    File from = new File(destinationDir, sourcetemp);
    File to = new File(destinationDir, destintemp);
    try {
        from.renameTo(to);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Rename failed", e);
    }
}
```

Hope that helped you.

Comment: k thank you..And if we store our DB in assets folder then how can we retrieve it in our code.will the above method works???

Answer (score 0):

You can find the DB path using below code:

```
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
{
              DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";         
            }
            else
            {              
DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
            }
```